# How many are the possible outcomes from throwing $n$ (identical) dice

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many are the possible outcomes from throwing $n$ (identical) dice.

I know it is a combination with repetition, but don't really know how to apply the formula.

I need an explanatory answer with the process of thinking.

The book's solution:

$$\binom{n + 5}{5}$$

Comment: It depends on whether the dice are distinguishable or not.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Try to modify your question in such a way that no one has to guess what you mean.

Comment: Consider you throw 2 dices. How many outcomes do you have? If they are distinguishable (die1, die2) then clearly 36 options (any number of die 1 and any number of die2). If you cannot distinguish them, then you have less options, as $((1,4)=(4,1))$ etc.

Comment: n+5 choose 5 is the indistinguishable option. That's just a formula for combinations with repetition.

Comment: I am trying to visualize it in my head, what indistinguishable means. Could you elaborate?

Comment: They are distinguishable if one is red and one is blue, for example. Then you count "$3$ on blue die and $5$ on red die" as a different outcome from "$3$ on the red die and $5$ on the blue die". But if you can't distinguish them, you only see "one $3$ and one $5$" and count it as one option, no matter how it is realized. In your case, you can't distinguish them, as the formula suggests.

Comment: The question said, identical dice, so I think it's indistinguishable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common way to explain it is known as "stars and bars".
I shall illustrate it putting identical balls into distinct bins ($1-6$) depicting the results obtained

One result with $n= 10$, say, would be $\;\;\bullet|\bullet|\bullet|\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet|\bullet
|\bullet\bullet\;\;$

Make two notes: only $5$ dividers are needed to depict $6$ bins, and you could have $0$ balls in some bins, e.g. $||\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet|\bullet\bullet\bullet|\bullet\bullet\bullet|$ depicting $0-0-4-3-3-0$

So if there are $n$ balls and $k$ bins ($k-1$ dividers), the only choice you have is to place the dividers among the lot, thus

$\dbinom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ which works out to $\dbinom{n+5}{5}$ for your particular example.

You could profitably look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) to have a more detailed explanation